# Probability of an at least n occurences of subsequences of length k in a RNA of length n

Tags: probability, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose we have a RNA sequence of length *N*,
then we have a subsequence of length *K*,

$K \le N$

Is there a method to calculate the probability of the subsequence occuring an *arbitrary number of times* **or** *at least an arbitrary number of times* in the sequence?

The probability of it happening at least once is simply:

$1-(1-\frac{1}{4^K})^{(N-k+1)}$

It is also easy to calculate the probability of it happenning at least *N* times, if the sequence consists of same consecutive letters (in other words it can overlap independently) is simply the above probability to the power of N:

$(1-(1-\frac{1}{4^K})^{(N-k+1)})^N$

But how to calculate it for an arbitrary sequence? 
Particularly I cannot wrap my head around the fact that some sequences can overlap while others cannot.
For example If I search for a sequence AAAAAAT and I find it on *k*-th place, it is clear that I wont observe it on the next *7* places, while for example after observing the sequence CGCGCGCG I can observe it again every two places for the length of 8.
Is there actually any expression for the probability? Or do I have to manually go through all the combinations?

Comment: How many subsequences "AA" are there in the sequence "AAAAA"?

Comment: The subsequence is present there 4 times.